# Meaning of もの in この世は誰一人変わらないものはいない

Tags: meaning

> この世は誰一人変わらない**もの**はいない

I don't understand why もの is here, if you already have 誰一人 here Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What would you propose as an alternative sentence?

Just taking out the もの (「この世は誰一人変わらないはいない」) is ungrammatical, because the は particle needs to take a noun, and 変わらない is not a noun.

You might be thinking that you could put 誰一人 in the place of もの, but 誰一人 is an expression that basically functions adverbially, not as a noun (as you can see by the fact that it does not need a particle following it here, etc), so that doesn't actually work either.

誰一人 is often translated as "no-one", but since it is essentially an adverb it might be better to think of it more as meaning something more like "no matter who" or "(not even) out of all possible people".  When viewed that way it becomes a bit more clear what is going on and why もの is still needed, I think:

> この世は誰一人変わらないものはいない
> In this world (この世は), no matter who it is (誰一人), a person (もの) who doesn't change (変わらない) does not exist (いない).